# [C]Dynamic allocation memory of structure, related to GTK

Tags: c, gtk, malloc, structure, allocation

I have following structure:

```
    typedef struct
{
 GtkWidget* PoziomaLinijka;
 GtkWidget* PionowaLinijka;
 GtkWidget* Label1;
 GtkWidget* Label2;
 gint x,y;
} StrukturaDrawing;
```

And i need to allocate it on the heap because later I have functions which uses that structure and I don't want to use global variables. So I allocate it like this:

```
    StrukturaDrawing* Wsk;
  Wsk = (StrukturaDrawing*)malloc(sizeof(StrukturaDrawing));
  if (!Wsk)
  {
 printf("Error\n");
  }
```

And it doesn't returning error and also works great with other functions, it works the way I wanted it to work so finally i wanted to free that memory and here is problem because in Debug Mode compilator bitches:

First-chance exception at 0x102d12b4 in GTK.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfffffffc.
Unhandled exception at 0x102d12b4 in GTK.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfffffffc.

I connect callback to my function, like that:

> g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(Okno), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(Wyjscie), Wsk);

Function which is suppose to free memory and close program:

```
void Wyjscie(GtkWindow* window, GdkEvent* event, StrukturaDrawing* data)
{
 gtk_main_quit();
 free(data);
 data = NULL;
}
```

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well durning debugging data structure have following values:
The first one has: PoziomaLinijka CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found
And later the whole rest have: PionowaLinijka CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

Oh: I am the oen who started question, sorry about confusing with nicknames.

Answer (score 0):

The "destroy" signal has a different signature for its callback than your `Wyjscie` function. Maybe you rather want the "destroy-event" of GtkWidget, see docs[here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-destroy-event)

If you want the "destroy" event of GtkObject, see [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkObject.html#GtkObject-destroy), you have to change your callback to

```
void Wyjscie(GtkObject* window,StrukturaDrawing* data)
{
 gtk_main_quit();
 free(data);
}
```